# @shopify/shopify-api nodejs - Set permanent access token for private app installed on only one store

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

The [shopifyApi reference](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/docs/reference/shopifyApi.md) does not have a private app permanent access token property. I have a custom private app that is installed on only one store and I have the permanent access token so I don't need to oAuth every time I'm calling the REST API. Would be great to have a documented straight forward example of how to do this. The docs are hairy, IMO.

- `@shopify/shopify-api` version: 6.1.0

Is the following close? I'm looking at the [Session object](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/docs/guides/session-storage.md#basics) and trying to understand how to load an offline session and set the `Session` with correct `SessionParams`.

```js
import '@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node'
import { shopifyApi, LATEST_API_VERSION, Session } from '@shopify/shopify-api'

const shopify = shopifyApi({
  apiKey: 'myprivateappkey',
  apiSecretKey: 'myprivateappsecret',
  apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
  isPrivateApp: true,
  scopes: ['read_products'],
  isEmbeddedApp: false,
  hostName: 'shop.myshopify.com',
})

const sessionId = shopify.session.getOfflineId('shop.myshopify.com')
const session = new Session({
  id: sessionId,
  shop: 'shop.myshopify.com',
  state: 'state',
  isOnline: false,
  accessToken: 'permanentAccessToken',
})

const client = new shopify.clients.Rest({ session: session })
```

On older v5 version of `shopify-api`, with two lines I could access any REST API, but I see this is now [deprecated](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/docs/migrating-to-v6.md#changes-to-api-clients), So I'm trying to unravel offline sessions, but it doesn't make sense to provide the api key and api secret and then create a session using the permanent access token.

```js
import Shopify from '@shopify/shopify-api'

const client = new Shopify.Clients.Rest(
  'mystore.myshopify.com',
  'permanentAccessTokenString',
)
```

Comment: Do you get any error with your setup?

Comment: I'm about to test it. I'll post if it works. Was hoping to get input before running it to know if this is the correct way to create a Shopify connection with a private app. I've also filed an issue with Shopify https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/issues/700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer from Shopify [here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/issues/700#issuecomment-1410780918).

> When creating the client in a private app, a dummy session can be created like so

```js
const session = new Session({
  id: 'not-a-real-session-id',
  shop: 'shop.myshopify.com,
  state: 'state',
  isOnline: false,
});

const client = new shopify.clients.Rest({ session: session })
```

> When config.isPrivateApp is set to true only the shop property is used by the client - the other three (id, state, isOnline) properties are ignored (but are required when creating a Session object).
> config.apiSecretKey is used as the access token, and is read directly from the config (no need to set the accessToken property of the dummy session as it will be ignored).
> Essentially, config.apiSecretKey is the permanent access token for a private app.

> The scopes can be omitted, as it defaults to an empty scopes array internally anyway and (from a quick search through the library code) is only used when doing OAuth, validating sessions, etc., which won't apply to private apps.

> As for the apiKey, while it's mostly used as part of the OAuth process, it is also used in a few other places (e.g., shopify.auth.getEmbeddedAppUrl()), so I'd recommend setting the apiKey to be that of your private app.

However, in my testing, scopes, even when `isPrivateApp`, are currently required. If you leave the array empty for `scopes` it will have a config error.

Also, my `shopifyApi` config [mounts rest resources](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/main/docs/guides/rest-resources.md#mounting-rest-resources) so that when you're in [Shopify REST docs](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/transaction#get-orders-order-id-transactions) on the nodejs tab, you can easily use the REST resources examples on the nodejs to make calls, rather than creating a REST client and use standard `post`, etc.

[image]

**Complete code to setup a private app connection to Shopify:**

```js
import '@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node'
import { shopifyApi, LATEST_API_VERSION, Session } from '@shopify/shopify-api'
import { restResources } from '@shopify/shopify-api/rest/admin/2023-01'
const debug = process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR === 'true'

const shopify = shopifyApi({
  apiKey: 'myprivateAppApiKey',
  apiSecretKey: 'myPermanentAccessToken',
  apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
  isPrivateApp: true,
  scopes: [
    'read_customers',
    'write_customers',
    'read_fulfillments',
    'write_fulfillments',
    'read_inventory',
    'write_inventory',
    'write_order_edits',
    'read_order_edits',
    'write_orders',
    'read_orders',
    'write_products',
    'read_products',
  ],
  isEmbeddedApp: false,
  hostName: debug ? '127.0.0.1:5001' : 'shop.myshopify.com',
  // Mount REST resources.
  restResources,
})

// Create a sanitized "fake" sessionId. E.g.
// "offline_my.myshopify.com".
const sessionId = shopify.session.getOfflineId('shop.myshopify.com')
const session = new Session({
  id: sessionId,
  shop: 'shop.myshopify.com,
  state: 'state',
  isOnline: false,
})

// Use mounted REST resources to make calls.
const transactions = await shopify.rest.Transaction.all({
  session,
  order_id: 123456789,
})

// Alternatively, if not using mounted REST resources
// you could create a standard REST client.
const client = new shopify.clients.Rest({ session })
```